# Finding the arrangment of some set of kernels between 0 and 1 that results in the maximum area under the conjoined curve

Tags: statistics, optimization

Firstly I apologize for not using the correct nomenclature; I do not know it.

Let $k(x)$ be some kernel and let there be $n$ functions $f_1(x),...,f_n(x)$ such that $f_i(x) = c_ik(x-p_i)$ and $\vec{c}, \vec{p} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Given some $\vec{c}$ and $k(x)$ what choice of $\vec{p}$ (where $p_i\in[0,1]$) maximizes the value of $\int_0^1g_n(x)dx$ where $g_n$ is recursively defined as:
$$g_1(x)=f_1(x)$$
$$g_i(x) = g_{i-1}(x) + f_i(x) - g_{i-1}(x)f_i(x)$$